# Picking the next task in Linux Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduler

What is the safest way to pick the next task (process) that the current CPU will execute, from a random place in a driver?

I saw **struct task_struct** (from sched.h) contains a **next_task** member, and thought a nice way to perform that mission is to get the current task with **current** macro, and use that member to pick the next one.

But, I saw the function **__schedule()** performs that mission in a different way - with functions like cpu_rq...

So, what's the correct way and the differences between the methods?

By the way, I saw two different definitions of the "current" task.

1. In sched.h: `#define current (0+current_set[smp_processor_id()])`
2. The more popular one from current.h: `#define current get_current()` that returns `percpu_read_stable(current_task)`

For my original solution, both sound good for me, but how is it possible that there are two macros with the same name? What are the differences between them?

Comment: the next task is in the https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/sched/signal.h#L643 file

Answer (score 0):

*What is the **safest way** to pick the next task (process) that the current CPU will execute,

from a **random place in a driver**?*

> ```
>    /* random place in a driver */
>     msleep_interruptible(20);
> ```
>
> <sub>*NOTE: Remember to `#include <linux/delay.h>`.*</sub>

The next task has now been "picked" to run on the current CPU. :-)

> On a more serious note,
>   **without involving the scheduler,
>
>   there is no way a driver can accurately determine (under all operating conditions)
>
>   the next task that will be scheduled on the CPU.**

---

*I saw struct `task_struct` (from sched.h) contains a next_task member, and thought a nice way to perform that mission is to get the current task with current macro, and use that member to pick the next one.*

> The `next_task` pointer is just used to maintain a global linked list of all the tasks in the system.
>   Not to be confused as the next task to be scheduled or anything like that.

<sub>References:

- [introduction to Linux Processes](http://linuxgazette.net/133/saha.html)

- [details of the process descriptor and the task structure](http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch03lev1sec1).</sub>

---

*What are the differences between the 2 definitions of `current` i.e.   `(0+current_set[smp_processor_id()]` and `percpu_read_stable(current_task)`?*

> Currently (**Linux kernel 4.4**),
>   the following 2 are the ONLY architecture-agnostic definitions of `current`

1. [`(current_thread_info()->task)`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/asm-generic/current.h#L6)

   - Maintained on the stack for quick retrieval.
   - Used by default in normal operating mode.
2. [`syscall(__NR_gettid);`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/lib/lockdep/common.c#L29)

   - Triggers a syscall to find the tid/pid of the current process.
   - Used when kernel has lockdep debugging is enabled.

> Both of these return a [`task_struct`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h#L1378)
>   containing the details of the current task that is active on the current CPU.